Is there a walking path between lower level West Vancouver and Cypress Pop-up Village?
I want to get to Cypress Pop-up Village via walking and/or Translink buses from lower level West Vancouver. Is this possible without a large detour through Eagle Lake Access road?
Google Maps says WB Westridge Ave @ Southridge Ave East, West Vancouver to Cypress Pop-Up Village requires walking through a restricted usage road.
The restricted usage road connects Wentworth Avenue and Cypress Bowl Road and is unnamed. The road is only about 350 meters long. Here are the street views:



going up
going down









The signs are:

going up

left

do not enter
no cycling


right

one way




going down

left

do not enter
except maintenance and authorized vehicles
no cycling
no thru road


middle

no green waste


right

do not enter
except maintenance and authorized vehicles
no cycling
no thru road






It doesn't say "no pedestrians" anywhere?

This appears to be a waste processing site with large vehicles using it.
I suspect it would not be a very safe route to use, althought it is unclear if it is explicitly forbidden.

@gerrit I can't say I've ever seen a "no pedestrians" sign before in Vancouver, so they might have used the "do not enter" and "no cycling" signs instead. The other signs posted also make it seem like we shouldn't be walking through it ("do not enter" and "no thru road").

@CMaster there appears to be construction nearby the village, so that might be the case. Note that I do not require going through the unnamed road, but only getting to the pop-up village from lower level West Vancouver, hopefully without taking the 6.3 km detour through Eagle Lake Access road (https://maps.app.goo.gl/yMzRz77y69BdfVP16).

Yes, the unnamed road is accessible via walking, but beware of trucks, workers, and loud noises. I went past a few workers while on that road and they gave me a thumbs up to pass.
For anyone planning to walk up this path to Eagle Bluffs or Eagle Lake, do not attempt! there is this sign posted, which is not readable in Google Maps street view:

It says:

Google is wrong
No access to Eagle Bluffs
No public access to Eagle Lake


Google is wrong No wonder Google blurred this image ;-)
